# CSS: Menu text hover effects (dual styles) help required

Tags: css, navigation

Been trying to figure this one out for a while, and decided to see if any of you could offer some light on the subject.

I have a menu/navigation with the page title in bold at the top, and a lighter description beneath it (see image below).

[image: image1]
http://cl.ly/5yiV

When hovered over, I want the menu items to display as follows:

[image: image2]
http://cl.ly/5ylG

I want it so that both lines of text change colour whether the top 'About Me' or the bottom 'Who am I?' is hovered over.

At the moment, I'm currently only able to get either line to change colour on hover.

Could anybody please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it if you wrap both parts into a link like:

```
<a href="#">ABOUT ME<span>Who Am I?</span></a>
```

Then you can use styling like:

```
a:hover {color:blue;}
a:hover span {color:red;}
```

You would of course use more sofisticated styling with use of classes.. but you should get the point from my simple example (If I understood your question correctly.)

Edit: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/vMAbD/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

I've just tried this out, and it works, but with one slight problem...

If the smaller text is hovered over, both the large text above it turns black, and the smaller text turns blue. However, if the larger text is hovered over, the smaller text turns to black with it too... if this makes sense? If not, I'll upload some screenshots.

Comment: It's supposed to work as that. Both texts are acting as a simple element - that anchor which acts as a wrapper and link at once. You can't unlink them with pure css solution. If you want the big part to be activating both color changes, but the smaller one's hover won't activate anything, then you have to use javascript or make the menu from images. (At least I don't know pure cross-browser css working solution for this).

Comment: So it seems like using images is the only way forward? Here's what I've got working so far - it's far from finished. Maybe this will make my issue clearer? [http://www.lukekendalldesign.co.uk/developmentzone/newwebsite/]

Comment: No, you can just use my solution (which deals with it as I am used to). I added link to demo to my answer.

Comment: If you want different behavior at each line of text, than you have to use more complex solution with javascript. But I don't see any reason why would you do that. This kind of navigations is (or at least was, when I was doing webdesign) done like I showed.

Comment: Thanks, I've just visited the working example you provided and this theoretically should work - I'll have a play around and let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: You just have to style the elements as you need, but the logic should be ok.

Comment: Solved it - I was using 'ul#nav li a span:hover' as opposed to 'ul#nav li a:hover span'. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the 'hover' event is triggered once you actually "hover" over a selected object.
If the img that you're posting is only one object itself, I think you'll have to divide it into 2 pieces and then put them together, that way you can set the hover trigger into both objects and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: The image that I uploaded is effectively two lines of text, which appears like this `<li><a href="#">WELCOME<br/><span>It all starts here.</span></a></li>` after following the advice above.